# How to make a <input> tag multi line?

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to know if is possible to make a `<input>` tag with appearance like  multi-line (similar to the `<TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA`>) using CSS or another option, unfortunately I can replace the tag  with  in my web application.

```
   <input id="uxMessage" validation="required" name="uxMessage" type="text" />
```

Many Thanks

Comment: No, not unless you turn it into a `textarea` somehow. You *could* do that relatively easily with jQuery, though.

Comment: You can style a textbox to be bigger, but I'm pretty sure it'll still be a single line.

Comment: yes Jeremy is still a single line.

Comment: @Why do you need that? You can style a textarea to look like a textbox, but be multiline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<input type="text" />` will always only be one line; You cannot force a multiple line behavior with CSS or JavaScript. You will need to use a `<textarea>` instead of a `<input>`.

You could use jQuery and it's [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method to replace the targeted `<input>` with a `<textarea>`. however this has obvious caveats, such as those who visit your page without JavaScript on.

Example:

```
<input id="uxMessage" validation="required" name="uxMessage" type="text" />

$("#uxMessage").replaceWith('<textarea id="uxMessage" name="uxMessage"></textarea>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Not without some pretty hefty Javascript, Textarea is the only multi-line text input that I know of.

**Edit**

Something like this might work with jQuery:

```
var textArea = jQuery('<textarea />').attr({'id': 'uxMessage', 'name': 'uxMessage'});
jQuery('#uxMessage').replaceWith(textArea);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the fields i wanted multiline, i set the input type="textarea".

then, i've run the following script at end of body:

```
    <script>
        $('input[type="textarea"]').each(function(index) {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.replaceWith($('<textarea/>').attr('name', elem.attr('name')).val(elem.val()));
        });
    </script>
```

it may not work, so selecting by a class should be better.
it doesn't work with jquery slim.

hope this may help you.